# При запуске сцены игрок перемещается немного вверх

Tags: c#, unity3d, разработка-игр

Я изучаю unity и вот попробовал сделать сцену но в процессе разработки столкнулся с проблемой. При запуске сцены игрока перемещает вверх на  0.015 по оси y. В коде есть проверка находится ли персонаж на земле, а так как у меня он не находится то я не могу прыгать.
Вот код:

```
{
    
    public float speed = 5f;
    public float jumpForce = 300f;
    private bool direction = true;

    bool isGrounded;

    private Rigidbody2D rb;

    void Start()
    {
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
    }

    void FixedUpdate()
    {   
        float move = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
        rb.velocity = new Vector2(move * speed, rb.velocity.y);

        if (move > 0 && !direction) {
            flip();
        }
        else if (move < 0 && direction){
            flip();
        }
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown("w") && isGrounded)
        {            
            rb.AddForce(Vector2.up * jumpForce);            
        }
    }

    private void flip() 
    {   
        direction = !direction;
        Vector2 theScale = transform.localScale;
        theScale.x *= -1;
        transform.localScale = theScale;
    }
    private void IsGroundedUpate(Collision collision, bool value)
    {
        if (collision.gameObject.tag == ("Ground"))
        {
            isGrounded = value;
        }
    }

    void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision)
    {
        IsGroundedUpate(collision, true);
    }

    void OnCollisionExit(Collision collision)
    {
        IsGroundedUpate(collision, false);
    }

    
}
```

[image: До запуска]

[image: После запуска]

Comment: у меня получилось выяснить что причиной является компонент rigidbody2D - если его удалить, все нормально. Я пробовал добавлять компонент прямо в коде и тогда тоже не работало.

Answer (score 0):

я надеюсь я смогу помочь, Попробуй сам куб неменого выше переместить мне кажеться что куб и пол пересикаються и Физика выталкивает куб верх чтобы он не застрял

если это не помогло проверь колайдер пола и куба
Если и это не помогло, Попробуй Вернуть Right body По умалчанию (Если ты его изменял)